# Javafx.fxml loader termination

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I couldn't find a solution how to fix following messages:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/stefanhegetschweiler/Downloads/AddressApp-Part-7-2/bin/ch/makery/address/view/PersonOverview.fxml:36

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
 at ch.makery.address.MainApp.showPersonOverview(MainApp.java:123)
 at ch.makery.address.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:81)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set ch.makery.address.MainApp field ch.makery.address.view.PersonOverviewController.mainApp to javafx.scene.control.Button
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
 at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:745)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
 ... 11 more
```

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    /**
     * The data as an observable list of Persons.
     */
    private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public MainApp() {
        // Add some sample data
        personData.add(new Person("Hans", "Muster"));
        personData.add(new Person("Ruth", "Mueller"));
        personData.add(new Person("Heinz", "Kurz"));
        personData.add(new Person("Cornelia", "Meier"));
        personData.add(new Person("Werner", "Meyer"));
        personData.add(new Person("Lydia", "Kunz"));
        personData.add(new Person("Anna", "Best"));
        personData.add(new Person("Stefan", "Meier"));
        personData.add(new Person("Martin", "Mueller"));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        // Set the application icon.
        this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(
                new Image("file:resources/images/address_book_32.png"));

        initRootLayout();

        showPersonOverview();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout and tries to load the last opened
     * person file.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Try to load last opened person file.
        File file = getPersonFilePath();
        if (file != null) {
            loadPersonDataFromFile(file);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
     */
    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            PersonOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens a dialog to edit details for the specified person. If the user
     * clicks OK, the changes are saved into the provided person object and true
     * is returned.
     * 
     * @param person
     *            the person object to be edited
     * @return true if the user clicked OK, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean showPersonEditDialog(Person person) {
        try {
            // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup dialog.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/PersonEditDialog.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Create the dialog Stage.
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Edit Person");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            dialogStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:resources/images/edit.png"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            // Set the person into the controller.
            PersonEditDialogController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
            controller.setPerson(person);

            // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
            dialogStage.showAndWait();

            return controller.isOkClicked();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens a dialog to show birthday statistics.
     */
    public void showBirthdayStatistics() {
        try {
            // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/BirthdayStatistics.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Birthday Statistics");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            dialogStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:resources/images/calendar.png"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            // Set the persons into the controller.
            BirthdayStatisticsController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setPersonData(personData);

            dialogStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the person file preference, i.e. the file that was last opened.
     * The preference is read from the OS specific registry. If no such
     * preference can be found, null is returned.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public File getPersonFilePath() {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainApp.class);
        String filePath = prefs.get("filePath", null);
        if (filePath != null) {
            return new File(filePath);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the file path of the currently loaded file. The path is persisted in
     * the OS specific registry.
     * 
     * @param file the file or null to remove the path
     */
    public void setPersonFilePath(File file) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainApp.class);
        if (file != null) {
            prefs.put("filePath", file.getPath());

            // Update the stage title.
            primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp - " + file.getName());
        } else {
            prefs.remove("filePath");

            // Update the stage title.
            primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads person data from the specified file. The current person data will
     * be replaced.
     * 
     * @param file
     */
    public void loadPersonDataFromFile(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(PersonListWrapper.class);
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

            // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
            PersonListWrapper wrapper = (PersonListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);

            personData.clear();
            personData.addAll(wrapper.getPersons());

            // Save the file path to the registry.
            setPersonFilePath(file);

        } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
            Dialogs.create()
                    .title("Error")
                    .masthead("Could not load data from file:\n" + file.getPath())
                    .showException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves the current person data to the specified file.
     * 
     * @param file
     */
    public void savePersonDataToFile(File file) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(PersonListWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            // Wrapping our person data.
            PersonListWrapper wrapper = new PersonListWrapper();
            wrapper.setPersons(personData);

            // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
            m.marshal(wrapper, file);

            // Save the file path to the registry.
            setPersonFilePath(file);
        } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
            Dialogs.create().title("Error")
                    .masthead("Could not save data to file:\n" + file.getPath())
                    .showException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data as an observable list of Persons.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData() {
        return personData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> below you can see the code of the controller. At the moment the app doesn't shows the
>   person overview and all other main functions like the buttons edit, delete and new.

```
 package ch.makery.address.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;

import ch.makery.address.MainApp;
import ch.makery.address.model.Person;

public class PersonOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lastNameLabel;
    @FXML


    // Reference to the main application.
    private MainApp mainApp;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public PersonOverviewController() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        // Clear person details.
        showPersonDetails(null);

        // Listen for selection changes and show the person details when changed.
        personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showPersonDetails(newValue));
    }

    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        // Add observable list data to the table
        personTable.setItems(mainApp.getPersonData());
    }

    /**
     * Fills all text fields to show details about the person.
     * If the specified person is null, all text fields are cleared.
     * 
     * @param person the person or null
     */
    private void showPersonDetails(Person person) {
        if (person != null) {
            // Fill the labels with info from the person object.
            firstNameLabel.setText(person.getFirstName());
            lastNameLabel.setText(person.getSecondEnglish());

        } else {
            // Person is null, remove all the text.
            firstNameLabel.setText("");
            lastNameLabel.setText("");

        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks on the delete button.
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleDeletePerson() {
        int selectedIndex = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            personTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        } else {
            // Nothing selected.
            Dialogs.create()
                .title("No Selection")
                .masthead("No Person Selected")
                .message("Please select a person in the table.")
                .showWarning();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the new button. Opens a dialog to edit
     * details for a new person.
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleNewPerson() {
        Person tempPerson = new Person();
        boolean okClicked = mainApp.showPersonEditDialog(tempPerson);
        if (okClicked) {
            mainApp.getPersonData().add(tempPerson);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the edit button. Opens a dialog to edit
     * details for the selected person.
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleEditPerson() {
        Person selectedPerson = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedPerson != null) {
            boolean okClicked = mainApp.showPersonEditDialog(selectedPerson);
            if (okClicked) {
                showPersonDetails(selectedPerson);
            }

        } else {
            // Nothing selected.
            Dialogs.create()
                .title("No Selection")
                .masthead("No Person Selected")
                .message("Please select a person in the table.")
                .showWarning();
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to show us your code

Comment: above you can see the main app or should I show something specific?

Comment: The PersonOverview.fxml and the controller would be helpful. Also removing the irrelevant parts would certainly be no mistake (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: It looks like the `FXMLLoader` is trying to assign a `Button` to the field that's supposed to hold your `MainApp`. Showing the FXML along with (at least) the parts of the controller that are pertinent to the `mainApp` property would help. As an aside, a controller having a reference to the application code that uses it is usually a bad design.

Comment: thank you for the hint that that a button tries to assign to the MainApp, the table view was mistakely linked to it. So now it works. Many Thanks to your comments!